# Instant Run funciona mas arquivo .apk não instala

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, build

Bom, o problema que estou enfrentando é que quando emulo o meu *app* através do *Instant Run* o *app* roda perfeitamente no meu *smartphone*. Porém, não consigo instalar o mesmo *app* através do `.apk` gerado.

Uso o **Android Studio 3.2.0.0**

**Obs.:** o `.apk` é gerado sem erros, mas ao tentar instalar aparece: O *app* não foi instalado.

Comment: uma pergunta boba, mas você desinstalou a versão depuração do instant run antes de instalar o apk manualmente?

Comment: Sim, desinstalei e inclusive já tentei rodar o apk até em outro aparelho, também não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Smartphone que você quer instalar o `.APK` é o mesmo do   **Instant Run** ? "Se sim" então provavelmente é o **PLAY PROTECT** que não permite você instalar aplicativos de fonte desconhecida. Pra resolver isso vá na sua conta do play store na aba de configurações e desative o serviço de proteção; "Se não" então observe a versão de API do Smartphone que você quer instalar e a API do seu aplicativo. Veja também em que pastas estão localizadas seus layouts e imagens (Ex.: Imagina que você tem apenas um arquivo de nome `main_activity.xml(v23)`. Este arquivo, só rodaria na versão de API V23 e se você quiser instalar o app em um Smartphone de API 16, vai dar ruim). Para resolver isso, tenha um arquivo `main_activity.xml` na pasta `layout` e outro na pasta `layout-v23`.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais seguro de gerar um APK que será instalado manualmente (fora do Android Studio) é utilizando o Gradle.

Com um terminal aberto na pasta do seu projeto, rode o seguinte comando para gerar um novo APK:

No Unix: `./gradlew assembleDebug`

No Windows: `gradlew assembleDebug`

Às vezes o APK gerado pelo Android Studio é parcial e/ou contém a flag `android:testOnly="true"` no AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Após esse comando obtive o seguinte erro no terminal:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: Como a mensagem de erro diz, você deve ter o Java instalado e a variável `JAVA_HOME` [configurada no seu `PATH`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

Comment: Obrigada, seu comentário com esse link me fez entender o que eu precisava fazer. 
Após dar o comando consegui executar, e aparentemente foi criado com sucesso. Apenas ainda não sei em que pasta o APK foi criado, visto que não está na pasta padrão de quando construo usando o Android Studio

Comment: Consegui fazer tudinho. Mas não funcionou. :(  o APK ainda não instala